# MYSQL DB timestamp not saving records. rather saves in datetime format

Tags: php, mysql, sql, date, datetime

i have a column that is a timestamp to store a date time. so i am inputting the time() result to save the value in to that column in database.

for example, result generated by time() = 1385714063 // a timestamp

```
echo time() //1385714063
```

I am adding 1385714063 (timestamp) and saving but it automatically converts 1385714063 in to 2013-11-14 00:00:00 which i dont understand how.

why i am not allowed to store the value as a timestamp(1385714063) or why is it doing the conversion is my question.

**UPDATE 1**

I tried, NOW() as explained in the first answer but it doesnt help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The TIMESTAMP data type is used for values that contain both date and time parts. TIMESTAMP has a range of '1970-01-01 00:00:01' UTC to '2038-01-19 03:14:07' UTC.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/datetime.html

You should insert your date in the format of `Y-m-d H:i:s`

Answer (score 1):

Try `echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s");` method to store date time .My sql Database uses formate.`now()` is mysql function not php

Comment: it says, Call to undefined function now()

Comment: Sorry check answer now

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW())
```

But i think TIMESTAMP datatype will store in "YYYY-mm-dd h:i:s" so for the timestamp you want you can use other datatype like bigint or varchar

Answer (score 1):

Datatype `timestamp` in MySQL is stored internally value as four-byte integer value, but externally, you need to work with this datatype as with string. If you want to store `timestamp` value as integer value in MySQL, then use datatype `INT`.